# Java file handling

Tags: java, file-io

here is my code:

```
public class Homework{
/**
 * This is a data mining program surveying various countries' Human Development
 * Index rank (1), which is a composite statistic of life expectancy, education, and income indices
 * used to rank countries in terms of human development. This code will also examine
 * these countries' research and development expenditure (2) (measured with respect to % of GDP),
 * their number of researchers (3), the percentage of graduates who are in science and
 * engineering (4), number of patents granted (to both residents and non-residents) (5),
 * the percentage of population which owns a computer (6) and the percentage of population
 * which uses the internet (7). The above is also the chronological order for my use of columns.
 * The data used ranges from 2002-2011.
 *
 * I decided to focus on the first 150 ranked countries (as they provide
 * the most data per column) while excluding the rest of the columns
 * (royalty and license fees,electrification rate and note,
 * percentage of population which has a fixed broadband internet and telephone)
 * as these columns provided either less or redundant information.
 * As a side note, I also manually cut out the countries' "(republic of)" or "(federal state of)"
 * in the Data4.csv file to facilitate searching for countries' data.
 *
 * https://data.undp.org/dataset/Table-12-Innovation-and-technology/jixu-gnyy
 *
 * @author mbizzzle
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 *
 */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the innovation and tech data mining table");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Data4.csv"));
        String data = "";

        while (input.hasNext()){
            data += input.nextLine();
            data += ";";

        }
        String[] rows = data.split(";");
        String[][] dataL = new String[rows.length][];
        int i = 0;
        for (String row : rows){
            dataL[i++] = row.split(",");

        }
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the country you would like to examine");
        String country = sc.next();

        for (int j = 0; j<rows.length; j++){
            if (country.toLowerCase().equals(dataL[j][1].toLowerCase())){
                System.out.println("\n \n \n");
                System.out.println("DATA COVERING AVERAGES BETWEEN 2002-2011 FOR "+ country.toUpperCase()+"\n");
                System.out.println("        ---------------------------------------------        \n");
                System.out.printf("HDI is ranked number %s out of "+dataL.length+" countries \n", dataL[j][0]);
                System.out.printf("Percent of GDP in Research and Development expenditure: %s  \n", dataL[j][2]);
                System.out.printf("Number of researchers involved %s \n", dataL[j][3]);
                System.out.printf("Percentage of graduates in Science and engineering : %s \n", dataL[j][4]);
                System.out.printf("Number of patents granted to residents and nonresidents : %s \n", dataL[j][5]);
                System.out.printf("Percentage of population using personal computers : %s \n", dataL[j][6]);
                System.out.printf("Percentage of internet users : %s \n", dataL[j][7]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all is working well to the exception of:

1. When I enter a country who's name is two letters (e.g:South Africa) the program terminates running and doesn't give me any data. I have already tried to set "South Africa".toLowercase.equals(dataL[122][1]) manually to check whether it was my array which had a problem, (where dataL[122][1] were the multidimensional array's coordinates for South Africa) in a boolean expression which gave me true so I'm not entirely sure what is going on here.
2. Would anyone have any idea how I could re-order the rows such that they are ordered according to a column (let's say I want the order of countries who use the internet the most, which is my last column).

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Comment: We don't have your input file. Learn how to use a debugger, and execute the code step by step to see what happens. Note that reading everything line by line, and concatenating all the lines, to split them right after, is extremely inefficient. And using a 2D array makes the code hard to read? You should use a List<Item> instead, where Item would be a class with a getCountry(), getRank(), etc. Then you'll google for "sort a list of objects in Java" and have the answer to your second question.

Comment: Also, note that `sc.next()` returns the next word, not the next line. So if the user enters South Africa, all you'll get is South.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of `[java.util.Scanner][1]`.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

I.e. if you enter `South Africa`, the method `Scanner.next` will return `South`, because then there is whitespace.

Also note that what you are doing is a simple *database*, but *not* data mining. There is no complex statistical analysis going on, but you are just implementing a `SELECT * FROM file.csv WHERE Column1 = ?` manually.